# hdd recognized as ssd after windows 10 update

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I received the Windows 10 update and installed it without any problems to a Lenovo computer running Windows 7.  So far, everything works fine except that
when I go to defragment the drive, the media type of `C:` drive is now labeled an SSD.

It cannot be analyzed or optimized, both being grayed out.

Is there a way to change this drive designation to the hard drive that it actually is?

Comment: Rare. How does it show in your device manager ? As a HDD or SSD ?

Comment: in the device manager the device shows as a sata disc device.  And thanks for the reply

Comment: SSD's & HDD's both come with SATA connector. Does is specifically say **SATA Disc Device** ?

Comment: yes, its a WDC and says sata disk device

Comment: Have you tried updating your BIOS ? Are you on RAID ?

Comment: No i haven't upgraded the bios and no raid present.

Comment: Just the single drive and the 3 partitions all say ssd

Comment: Check if you have enabled AHCI mode in BIOS. Else try updating the BIOS

Comment: ok....thanks....ahci is already enabled.....bios from 2011....i see if there is a new version

Comment: **Set it to SATA mode & see**. just guessing though as you seem to be only one having this issue. Cannot find anything of this sort in whole internet that you are going through

Comment: Thanks.....no bios update available.....i checked for a more current ahci  driver, but its had the latest...i'll give it a few days and see if anyone else has a similar problem....

Comment: I thought you were the only one with this problem but i was wrong :/

Comment: One thing i can tell you , a 3rd party defragger wont get restricted by logic the sytem is using to prevent that. mydefrag of at least the earlier versions wil still be using the windows API and will still defrag a real SSD.

Comment: As an update:  I changed the hdd to a sandisk ssd...no speed advantage at all, but the SSD was still recognized as an SSD.  Made all of the necessary adjustments, but still not worth the cost of the drive on this older sata2 machine.  Decided to revert back to windows 7 but could not revert back using the SSD.  Put the original hard drive back into the machine and can now revert back to windows 7.  None of this was worth it.

Comment: final:  the new ssd works as it should in windows 7....recognized correctly, speed is much faster than the hdd.  To venture a guess this might have worked out differently if the SSD was installed to windows 7 before the upgrade to windows 10.  However, that still doesn't answer why windows 10 addressed the original hard drive as an SSD in the first place.